# Need to split (cutout a part of) the result of a powershell command into a CSV

Tags: powershell, split

I have a command that spits outs Active Directory SamAccountName, Description, Distinguished name into a CSV.  My issue is that I only need the part of the distinguished name after the user name.  I know this is conceptually simple, but I don't know enough about using Splits to get the results.

Here is my command:

```
get-content users.txt | get-aduser -pr 
    SamAccountName,Description,DistinguishedName | select 
        SamAccountName,Description,DistinguishedName | Export-Csv users.csv
```

Here is my output:

> Line1-- "user1","user1 description","CN=Lastname\, Firstname(user1),OU=OU2,OU=OU1,OU=Site-1,OU=Accounts_User,DC=domain,DC=company,DC=com"
>
> Line2--- "user2","user2 description","CN=Lastname\, Firstname,OU=OU1,OU=Site-2,OU=Accounts_User,DC=domain,DC=company,DC=com"

What I need is to drop the `CN=username2(username2),` part of the result.  So that my output looks like:

> "user2","user2 description","OU=OU1,OU=Site-2,OU=Accounts_User,DC=domain,DC=company,DC=com"

Comment: Are you wanting to drop the CN for just the second line or...?

Comment: Could you please use the standard formatting, so it is easire to read and understand your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object` dynamic expressions to manipulate a property and return that as part of your results, by constructing a select expression like:

```
Select-Object @{Name="NewName"; Expression={..any scriptblock..}}
```

In your case, I would remove the unwanted string part with a regex, by matching the `CN=([^=]*),OU=` and leaving only the `OU=` part only:

```
$_.DistinguishedName -ireplace "CN=([^=]*),OU=","OU="
```

So Altogether:

```
get-content users.txt |
get-aduser -pr SamAccountName,Description,DistinguishedName |
Select SamAccountName,Description, @{Name="NewDN"; Expression={$_.DistinguishedName -ireplace "CN=([^=]*),OU=","OU="}} |
Export-Csv users.csv
```

Comment: This produced exactly the results I was looking for.  I apologize that my question wasn't formatted well and my request wasn't clear.  I will make sure to improve in the future.